# ScriptManager AsyncPostBackError Tras varios postbacks seguidos

Tags: c#, jquery, script, async, updatepanel

Hola usuarios de stackoverflow en español. Les saludo afectuosament y agradezco sus comentarios tan acertados. Quiero solicitar su apoyo de la comunidad para la siguiente situación:

Tengo una pantalla donde tengo varios updates panel y varias ventanas modales que utilizo para una inserción.

Entonces, surgió un problema que ya detecté como reproducirlo, pero no sé como solucionarlo.

En dicha pantalla tengo un formulario que llena el usuario. Y, yo valido que todos los datos tengan que ser llenados para poder realizar una inserción en MYSQL y abrir una ventana modal. El detalle es que cuando presiono un botón que es para guardar, sino tiene todos los datos le genera una leyenda (con un label) para decirle que falta información. El problema es que cuando yo quiero darle click de nuevo al botón (exactamente al 3° click), me aparece el siguiente error en la consola:

```
****Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: ScriptManager_AsyncPostBackError at Function.Error$create [as create].****
```

He ido al log de IIS y no me dice más detalles. También, en la pantalla puse un script como este:

**

```
<script>
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_error() != undefined) {               
                console.log(args.get_error());
            }
        }    </script>
```

**

Y sigue saliendo el mismo error. Una vez que sucede dicha situación, si presiono cualquier otro botón que genera postback, deja de funcionar y marca el mismo error. Para que vuelva a funcionar, necesito recargar la página. Entonces...¿podrían darme sugerencias de donde buscar el error? También puse el update panel como always (lo tenía en condicional), pero me sigue marcando el mismo error.

Revisé el viewstate y no me aparece nada guardado. También coloqué un try catch, pero no entra. Coloqué el método de ScriptManager_AsyncPostBackError en el master (el scriptmanager está en el master) y no entra tampoco. Lo curioso es que solo sucede ese error en esa pantalla, en las demás no.

Como un detalle más, cuando esa página la corro en el servidor, el error del scriptmanager me lo marca de la siguiente manera:

```
**Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.**
```

He tratado de muchas maneras, pero no logro resolver el error...¿podrían ayudarme? Por favor.

Muchas gracias, que tengan una excelente tarde.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de mucho tiempo encontré el error: Este bloqueo sucedía cuando no realizaba el update de ciertos updatePanels. Desconozco el motivo, pero al dar update por medio de código en un postback, ya funcionó.

Espero que a alguien le sirva mi respuesta.